# Special Sort in views

Tags: views

I have a series of image,each image has it's own thumbnail(because cropping and scaling not suitable for some of images ),when user upload a image, upload thumbnail too,also I provide a field "class size" ( it is select list with 4 values (180,240,300,360) that indicate thumbnail width).
I want create a views that sort thumbnails like below picture (and if rows is more than 11 this sequence will be repeat)

[image]

[image]

**anybody has idea how can I do it?**

Comment: have you thought about using masonry?

Comment: There is a masonry module and a masonry views module.

Comment: @ScottJoudry how can I setup this patern in views result? I didn't find anything about che arrangement of views rows by masonry,I don't want user change(drag)them,I want when load , with this arrangement will be load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Drupal Isotope module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_isotope) (or [Masonry](https://www.drupal.org/project/masonry_views))that uses the [isotope jquery plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) with the [Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) would work perfect in this situation.  If the module does not work for you consider just using the plugin with a custom views template

Comment: I dont want user change(drag) them, I just want when load with this situation load,what is relation between my pattern and these modules?

Comment: Masonry will automatically align your images in the format you have in your above images, isotope just allows to filter masonry laid images.  but in your case you wouldn't use isotope but instead simply use masonry views.

Comment: @chadpepers how? I dont see any option is views option,or any readme file in modules !!!
how can I do this ?